# sql create a function

Tags: mysql, sql, string, function

Could someone please help me with this one? 
So I need to write a user input function in which I need to concatenate two strings. When outputted, there must be a space between the two strings, note there is not a space in the two strings when  inputting them. Test functions with the following, String 1: Spring, String 2: Break!

This is my solution:

```
create function concatenate(X CHAR,Y CHAR)
Returns CHAR(50)
Return concat(X, ' ', Y);

select concatenate('Spring','Break')
```

However, the problem is that sql only returns the first letter of each word, which is **"S B"**. But I want it to be **"Spring Break"**
Any ideas on this one? Helps are very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply a length for the input parameters as well:

```
create function concatenate(X CHAR(24),Y CHAR(24))
Returns CHAR(50)
Return concat(X, ' ', Y);

select concatenate('Spring','Break')
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Really appreciate your help

Comment: In this case pls mark the answer as accepted to indicate to other viewers thst the wuestion has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the size when you declare the argument.

```
create function con(X char(50), Y char(50))
returns char(100)
```

Comment: What is the point of repeating the same answer that's been provided before?

Comment: There's no point.. I opened the page and it had a wrong answer at that time. I added a new one and I see the answer has already been posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the size of CHAR(), otherwise it will use the default CHAR(1), and you can't get want you want.

eg:

```
create function hello(x char(10),y char(10)) 
     returns char(30) deterministic 
     return concat(x,' ',y)`

     select hello('Hello','World');
       Hello World
```